# Agarrar una fecha en Moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

En primer lugar tengo que hacer una función que compare data de una API con data puesta en los parámetros del componente y completar las fechas intermedias entre los parámetros que no vinieron de la API. El problema es que al tomar la fecha de un objeto Moment.js para compararla con otra fecha me devuelve un valor vacío.
La función por el momento es la siguiente:

```
  function adapterFunction(data) {
    const step = interval === "hour" ? "hours" : "days";
    const current = moment(since_str);
    const until = moment(until_str);
    const result = [];
    
    while (current <= until) {
      let item = { date: current, count: null };
      let dataItem = data.filter((i) => i.date === current);
      result.push(dataItem); //Acá es donde se colocan arrays vacíos
      current.add(1, step);
    }
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
```